# HTML element with # to pug-template

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, pug

I've got a piece of code with 2 angular material radio buttons. Both of them have the #attribute/element  (I'm not certain what it's called) within them. How can I convert them into pug so that the attribute/element with the # works? Here is sample code which has the #attribute/element in it that I'd like to make work in pug:

```html
<mat-radio-button #firstRadio name="selection" value="one" (change)="aMethodCall();" color="primary" [checked]="oneSelected"> ...
</mat-radio-button>
<mat-radio-button #secondRadio name="selection" value="two"  (change)="aMethodCall();" color="primary" [checked]= "!oneSelected"> ...
</mat-radio-button>
```

I've tried to turn it to pug:

```
mat-radio-button( #firstRadio, name="selection", value="one", (change)="aMethodCall()", color="primary", [checked]="oneSelected") ...
mat-radio-button( #secondRadio, name="selection", value="two", (change)="aMethodCall()", color="primary", [checked]="!oneSelected") ...
```

But the #elements are not registering in pug. Any help with the syntax to get them to work is appreciated.
Ps. if you know the name of the #element I'd like to know it. Thanks.

Comment: `#` is an [interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html) symbol in pug so there might be some issues there.  [This codepen](https://codepen.io/pacific202/pen/zXwZQP) generates `<div #firstradio="#firstRadio">firstRadio</div>` so what exactly do you want?

Comment: I'm under the impression that the # character is something else when used in an html element? so how can I convert the html with the # characters to pug is my quesiton. Given I know that I can just put it in as regular html and it will work, but say I wanted to make it work with 100% pug

Comment: Pug is an html preprocessor, so whatever it says `#` is wins.  There's also [plain text](https://pugjs.org/language/plain-text.html) in pug.

Comment: # can be an interpolation symbol if you use before brackets, like this #{ } or 3[ ], like @Graham commented. Or can be an html id, for example #MyRowId.MyClassRow. 
You can use https://html2jade.org/ to translate from html to pug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:
getting the html with the # id tag to work 100% on pug, I used the html2jade which Sergi Nadal suggested.
The resulting pug is then:

```
mat-radio-button(#firstradio='', name='selection', value='one', (change)='aMethodCall();', color='primary', [checked]='oneSelected')
  | ...
mat-radio-button(#secondradio='', name='selection', value='two', (change)='aMethodCall();', color='primary', [checked]='!oneSelected')
  | ...
```

So to bypass the # from working as a interpolation marker in pug, I can put it as an attribute with an empty value into the pug template to get it working.